# sql group by date gives same value everyday

Tags: mysql, sql, unix-timestamp

So I want to group by days for statistics so I have data on each day (type 1 is bought and 0 is sold) but the query gives me the same result everyday and that is not correct can someone help me with this code?

```
SELECT 
            DATE(from_unixtime(credit_transaction_time)) AS data_date,
            total_spend AS credits_spend,
            total_bought AS credits_bought
        FROM credit_transactions
            JOIN (SELECT SUM(`credit_transaction_amount`) AS total_spend FROM credit_transactions WHERE `credit_transaction_type` = 0 GROUP BY DATE(from_unixtime(credit_transaction_time))) AS spend
            JOIN (SELECT SUM(`credit_transaction_amount`) AS total_bought FROM credit_transactions WHERE `credit_transaction_type` = 1 GROUP BY DATE(from_unixtime(credit_transaction_time))) AS bought
        GROUP BY DATE(from_unixtime(credit_transaction_time))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT DATE(from_unixtime(credit_transaction_time)) AS data_date,
       SUM(CASE WHEN credit_transaction_type = 0 THEN credit_transaction_amount ELSE 0 END) as credits_spend,
       SUM(CASE WHEN credit_transaction_type = 1 THEN credit_transaction_amount ELSE 0 END) as credits_bought
FROM credit_transactions
GROUP BY DATE(from_unixtime(credit_transaction_time));
```

Your query doesn't work because you don't have an `ON` condition.  In most databases, this would result in a syntax error, but MySQL allows this syntax.

Comment: Thanks totally did the trick I had no idea I could use conditions in sql :)